# Has anyone else had problems reading from one individual spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have some code running in NodeJs using the standard googleapis client which has been working fine for months but starting last night when I perform a simple read on a range of cells in one of my spreadsheets I've been getting an internal error returned from the api with the message 'The service is currently unavailable.' I also get the error when attempting the same read through the explorer interface on the Google developer website.

I've now copied all the data to a second spreadsheet which is now, as far as I can see, identical to the first and from that I can both read and write data normally with no problems.

Has anyone come across a similar issue and can explain what the problem is and whether I can avoid it happening again in the future?

Comment: What kind of Http error code you've experienced? And have you checked your usage limit of your API request?

Comment: Hey Jess. It's a 503 error and I can't see that it can be related to usage limits for a number of reasons:

Comment: 1. Calling endpoints other than spreadsheets.values.get using the same authorisation on that sheet - spreadsheets.get for example to list the contained sheets - works fine.
2. The same authorisation is able to get data from other sheets documents with no problem.
3. Stopping the app and waiting before trying again still fails.
4. Using a different account in the explorer interface in the Google developers site also fails to read data from that sheet with the same error.